# I might've overdosed innerHTML and get undefined

Tags: javascript, html

```js
 function promptuj() {
   this.x = prompt("How big should be your multiplication table?");
   document.getElementById("keks").innerHTML = tabliczka(this.x);
 }

 function tabliczka() {
   document.getElementById("keks").innerHTML += "<table border=\"1\">";
   for (i = 1; i <= this.x; i++) {

     document.getElementById("keks").innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + i + "</td>";
     for (j = 1; j <= this.x; j++) {
       if (j != 1) {
         document.getElementById("keks").innerHTML += "<td>" + j * i + "</td>";
       }

     }
     document.getElementById("keks").innerHTML += "</tr>";
   }
   document.getElementById("keks").innerHTML += "</table>";
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Demo</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" onclick="promptuj()" value="Promptonto" />
  <div id="keks"></div>

</html>
```

This short thingie is for multiplication table with prompt button, asking how big should it be. But giving it any number returns undefined instead of a table.
Before that I had document.write(whatever) instead of document.getElementById("keks").innerHTML += and it worked.

EDIT: I noticed I didn't close `<body>` but it didn't help.

Comment: Never use `.innerHTML +=`!!!

Comment: @Oriol then what should I use instead? :|

Comment: @Andrew L. I just defined it outside of the function and it didn't matter. It worked without defining it when I used document.write().

Comment: you pass `this.x` to the `tabliczka()` function, but you don't use the argument in that function

Comment: @Irevall: The DOM is not a string of HTML. It makes no sense to add a closing tag to a DOM. You add whole elements, which can be parsed out of a valid HTML structure using `.innerHTML`, if you wish to take that appraoch.

Comment: @squint: I followed the code from answers (that stated same thing as you do) and it worked! Is there a way to mark this as solved or something?

Comment: you use `this.x` directly instead of as an argument of the function. Notice the difference in @Oriol's answer, `x` is passed to the function and used in the function and `this` is not used.

Comment: innerHTML is NOT like writing out code line by line. When you write out a open tag and add it, the parser closes that tag.

Comment: @epascarello but I can use document.write like writing line by line?

Comment: @Irevall: When `document.write` operates while the DOM is being created, it lets you inject arbitrary HTML markup as the HTML is being parsed. So because scripts by default block the parser, if you call `document.write()` in the script, it will simply *write* that new HTML in the position directly after the script, so that when the script finally finishes, the new HTML is there, ready to be parsed. The parser doesn't really know how it got there. It just parses it into the DOM as though it was any other HTML that came from the server.

Answer (score 2):

You get undefined because in `promptuj` you set the `innerHTML` to the value returned by `tabliczka`. But `tabliczka` doesn't explicitly return anything, so it's like it returned `undefined`.

Instead, `tabliczka` should return the HTML string to be set as the `innerHTML`.

Moreover, never use `.innerHTML +=`. Concatenate strings first, and assign `innerHTML` at the end. If you use `.innerHTML = "<table>"`, the parser will automatically close the table, without waiting for your `.innerHTML += "</table>"`. Then the contents will be inserted outside the table. And not relevant here, but `.innerHTML +=` also removes internal data, e.g. event listeners.

```js
function promptuj() {
  var x = prompt("How big should be your multiplication table?");
  document.getElementById("keks").innerHTML = tabliczka(x);
}
function tabliczka(x) {
  var str = "<table>";
  for (var i=1; i<=x; i++) {
    str += "<tr>";
    for (var j=1; j<=x; j++) {
      str += "<td>" + j*i + "</td>";
    }
    str += "</tr>";
  }
  str += "</table>";
  return str;
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="promptuj()" value="Promptonto" />
<div id="keks"></div>
```

Comment: So I indeed overdosed innerHTML? :P

Comment: This is a clean and nice solution, but was the `.innerHTML +=` part really what caused the problem? Isn't that more a (very) bad idea because of performance?

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg Well, there were some problems. The result was undefined because `tabliczka` didn't return anything. But `.innerHTML +=` is not only bad for performance. If you use `.innerHTML = "<table>"`, the parser will automatically close it, without waiting for your `.innerHTML += "</table>"`. Then the contents will be inserted outside the table. And not relevant here, but `.innerHTML +=` also removes internal data, e.g. event listeners.

Comment: Yeah exactly, and some other problematic things you cleaned up. Now I have realized that my comment above was not well thought through, and that, as others have mentioned in comments, you can't just write snippets of HTML to .innerHTML as if it was a string.

Comment: @Oriol you could add your comment into the answer, it adds a lot of value to your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function promptuj() {
            window.x=prompt("How big should be your multiplication table?");
            document.getElementById("keks").innerHTML = tabliczka(window.x);
        }

        function tabliczka(x) {

            var htmlString = "";

            htmlString += "<table border=\"1\">";
            for (i=1; i<=window.x; i++) {

                htmlString  += "<tr><td>" + i + "</td>";
                for (j=1; j<= x; j++) {
                    if (j!=1) {
                    htmlString  += "<td>" + j*i + "</td>";
                    }

                }
                htmlString  += "</tr>";
            }
            htmlString  += "</table>";

           return htmlString;
        }



    </script>
```

You saw undefined, because your tabliczka function originally returned nothing, so javascript implicitly returned undefined from the call to it (this is how javascript works).

So basically, even if tabliczka was correct, it did the innerHTML changes to your "keks" div and returned so the promptuj function did the final .innerHTML to "keks" with the result of tabliczka which was undefined.

It just happened so fast that you just saw undefined from what I can tell.

Comment: So promptuj() wanted some string/value from tabliczka() and found nothing, because tabliczka() only wanted to add things to HTML?

Comment: I'd like to +1 since the analysis of why the original solution didn't work seems spot on, but you've kept the poor `this.x` solution and the incorrect function argument approach so I'm not ready to endorse this just yet :)

Comment: Yes that's basically correct. In javascript, a function call by default returns undefined, unless you explicitly return something.

For example, if I have function myFunction() { /*do nothing*/ }, when I call it using myFunction(), I will get undefined.
Whereas if I have function myFunction { return 0; } , when I call it, it will return 0.

In your code, you were doing: 

 document.getElementById("keks").innerHTML = tabliczka(this.x); which says "put whatever is returned by tabliczka in the div "keks"" but tabliczka was returning undefined.

That's why you saw undefined.

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg, you are right. I just replaced this.x with window.x in order to be more explicit.
This is indeed a poor solution. I just didn't change everything to avoid that cause I am lacking the context in which this code was written and I wanted to help Irevall understand what the original problem was, without over-complicating my answer. But yes, you are absolutely correct that I wouldn't code like this in production.

Comment: @Peter Herdenborg: could you elaborate what's wrong with this.x and argument aproach?

Comment: @klikas: what's the difference between this.x and window.x?

Comment: @Irevall this.x basically creates an x variable in the global scope (i.e. in the window object). This is generally a bad practice when you code.

this.x and window.x in your example are no different cause when you call a function as a function (not a method of an object etc.), inside the function, this points to the window.

You can see some more info about "this" here: 

http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/

it is generally a big question the one you asked :)

Comment: @klikas: and "incorrect function argument approach"? :| You fixed my problem and it works perfectly now, but if there is anything else I could improve on, I'd love to. <3

Comment: @Irevall as klikas also explains, `this` in this context is the `window` object, and setting `this.x = 'y'` is exactly the same as creating a global variable outside of a function or inside a function but omitting the `var` keyword. Normally you just refer to `this` in the context of an object with member functions, where `this` refers to the object. If you code in *strict mode*, which is recommended, using `this` the way you do would cause an error. Also, you pass `this.x` as an argument in the function, but `tabliczka` takes no arguments. Instead, the global variable is accessed inside.

Comment: @Irevall, in order to have a better structure for your code, I would do something like this: 

https://jsfiddle.net/a0u6hq0z/

Firstly, this doesn't add global variables to the window and it removes the event from the HTML inline, but adds this unobtrusively.

Also it uses a self-executing function, to enclose everything in a scope and not expose anything to the window object.

It also handles the case when a user doesn't enter a valid integer.

Please copy this code and run it in another file cause I thing jsfiddle, doesn't allow prompts and alerts.

Comment: @Irevall I am trying the exact same code in an HTML file and it works. It would be useful if you could use an online editor to link to the HTML you are using in order to see why it doesn't work for you.